# Error Could not resolve entry module React + Rollup

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs

I need to build shareable React component which could be used across apps.

For this, I was/am following the below article

- https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library

My Configuration looks exactly the same except the npm packages version (even tried with the same versions)

The folder structure looks the same as below

[image]

rollup.config.js

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
{
 input: "src/index.ts",
 output: [
  {
    file: packageJson.main,
    format: "cjs",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  {
    file: packageJson.module,
    format: "esm",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
],
plugins: [resolve(), commonjs(), typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" })],
},
{
 input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
 output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
 plugins: [dts()],
},
];
```

npm script

```
"rollup": "rollup -c"
```

However when I run `npm run rollup` this throws the below error

> [!] Error: Could not resolve entry module (dist/esm/types/index.d.ts). 
> Error: Could not resolve entry module (dist/esm/types/index.d.ts)

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Change ```dist/esm/types/index.d.ts``` -> ```dist/esm/index.d.ts``` in rollup.config.js

Comment: @Eliot yes your suggestion fixed the issue. A Big Thank you. :)

Comment: @Eliot Your suggestion works. Thanks a lot

Comment: So changing to `input: "dist/esm/index.d.ts"` did not work for me. These are the package versions I used `"@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup": "^3.10.1",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.1.1",`

Comment: @Georgios i am running into the same issue, how did you solve?

Comment: @jamesemanon I did not. I ditched typescript and continued with plain js which worked.

Answer (score 16):

I also ran into the same problem you are experiencing when working with rollup. After spending some while digging for the solution, I finally got to solve this problem.

> My Configuration looks exactly the same except the npm packages version (even tried with the same versions)

*The exception you have stated is actually the problem. The problem lies in package versioning*. The package `@rollup/plugin-typescript` versions later than `8.3.3` are not generating nor storing the declaration files in the `types` folder expected to be at the path: `dist/cjs/` and `dist/esm/`.

The latest version at this point in time is `8.5.0` which still breaks. Hopefully it is fixed in near future.

### Steps to fix your error

- Make sure your `tsconfig.json` file has `"declarationDir": "types"` to direct the bundler's typescript plugin to create and store declaration files in the `types` folder when you run `npm run rollup`
- Uninstall the existing `@rollup/plugin-typescript` package version by running `npm un @rollup/plugin-typescript --save-dev`
- Install `@rollup/plugin-typescript` with the command `npm i @rollup/plugin-typescript@8.3.3 --save-dev`. *As you see, we are picking a specific version*.

### If you still encounter problems:

- Manually update the `package.json` file like: `"@rollup/plugin-typescript": "8.3.3"`. **Note that** I have removed the caret(`^`) symbol to tie the package to version `8.3.3`.
- Delete the `node_modules` folder. You could use the command `rm -rf node_modules`.
- Delete `package-lock.json`.
- Run `npm i` to install the packages again with versions specified in `package.json`

## UPDATE

---

This issue is fixed as from version `10.0.0`. Things should work normally without being stuck at an old version.

Comment: Using the exact version of `@rollup/plugin-typescript@8.3.3` solved it for me

Comment: Is there a GitHub issue that we can follow for updates on `@rollup/plugin-typescript`?

Comment: rollup seem to be having many issues. Can someone provide a webpack configuration for the similar setup, please?

Comment: @Maria This issue is fixed. You can install latest version which at time of this writing is `11.0.0`. It should work

Answer (score 9):

Here's an working answer for people coming from 2023 that doesn't lock you to an outdated version of `@rollup/plugin-typescript`:

**Preconditions:** Make sure that you get rid off your `package-lock.json` and your `node_modules` directory so that you can start from a clean slate and install your project again.

1. run `npm install tslib --save-dev`
2. add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`
3. in `tsconfig.json`, add `"rootDir": "src"`
4. in `rollup.config.js`, change `plugins: [dts()]` to `plugins: [dts.default()]`
5. back in `package.json`, add `--bundleConfigAsCjs` as a parameter to the `rollup` command in `scripts`

After that you should be able to continue with the tutorial and be able to create a new build via `npm run rollup`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything , I solved by this

In `rollup.config.mjs` In Plugins I changed this

```
   typescript({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json'
   })
```

Into this

```
   typescript({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
      declaration: true,
      declarationDir: 'dist',
   })
```

You must also put declaration and declarationDir here

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error of 'Could not resolve entry module (dist/esm/index.d.ts)'.

I tried removing types, downgrading react to match the version in the tutorial but none worked.

I found this comment on the tutorial which was helpful: https://dev.to/nasheomirro/comment/239nj

- I got rid of main and common js set up in both rollup config and package json.
- i changed the packagejson variable to `import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };`
- added types back into the input in the rollup config
- Set "@rollup/plugin-typescript" to be version "8.3.3" as mentioned above.

I now have a Dist folder with an ESM folder and didn't get any errors.